# С чего начать обживание Debian новичку?

Tags: debian

Установил Debian, но разрешение 640x800 и больше не делается, в интернет не выходит, хотя по локальной сети связь есть, звука тоже нет, предустановленного ПО нет. Как мне сделать так чтобы устранить все эти недостатки, а именно: установить ПО, драйвера, подключиться к интернету?

В Линуксе я полный чайник. Умею только устанавливать Debian и только научился вызывать консоль. Кстати, заодно буду рад ответу на вопрос: Почему в Линуксе не приживаются вирусы и зачем так сделано, что все операции надо производить из командной строки, ведь ему тогда почти не нужен графический интерфейс?

Всем заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу тебе как человек, однажды перерелезший с мандривы на дебиан.

Да, сперва все было как-то непонятно,неуклюже и неудобно настроено (вернее совсем не настроено).

1. Конфигурируем интерфейс. (Маны, гуглы, доки, чтение)*n раз. Повторять пока не придет просветление. Если не пришло - идем на форумы и мучаем всех такими вопросами. Хотя бы для начала чтоб роутер пинговать можно было, потом локальную сеть (при наличии), потом узнаем, что такое таблица роутинга, читаем, думаем, настраиваем.
2. Подключаем интернет. Узнаешь какое соединение у тебя и гуглишь на эту тему. В моем случае гуглозапрос выглядел как "pptp соединение в debain". Мне помог скрипт, выложеный mr.Peabody для впн от корбины.
3. Инет подключен? Тогда ставим дрова на видео, гуглозапрос вида "установка драйверов nvidia в debian"
4. Если есть нтфс диски-прикручиваем их.Как обратиться к гуглу - сам догадаешься уже, наверное.
5. Про установку программ-запусти от рута synaptic - это менеджер прог, он их ставит/удаляет, разруливает конфликты/зависимости (если может)

---

Отныне - гугл твой луший друг и поисковик нумер адын)

Comment: А так-как грится-читай матчасть)

Answer (score 1):

Как указал товарищъ выше - придётся много гуглить. В своё время я, оказавшись перед похожей ситуацией, взял бумажку и листик, и в порядке значимости выписывал туда всё, что не нравится и всё, что не работает. Конечно, порядок потом поменялся, но и понимания добавилось. И так вот, вычёркивая пунктик за пунктиком, освоился, обородился и освитерел :)

А вирусы в Linux-мире есть. И уязвимости есть. Только вот рядовые пользователи с ними практически не встречаются. Эти самые рядовые пользователи под рутом не сидят, соответственно и вирус много зла не наделает и вреда ОС не нанесёт. К тому же, большинство софта попадает из оффициальных репозиториев, что уменьшает вероятность скачать инфицированное ПО. "Вирусы в Linux распространяются через "Ух ты! Дай посмотреть!"(С)

Графический интерфейс же - для пользователей. Это одно из средств безопасности ОС, как от злоумышленника, так и от пользователя - чем меньше настроек видит пользователь, тем меньше вероятность что он "случайно нажмёт".Linux используется в огромном количестве устройств, на многих из них графический интерфейс не нужен или невозможен, а консоль, в таком случае, есть унифицированное средство настройки. Да и это круто смотриться со стороны =)

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю главное, что нужно понять - зачем мне Linux? Какой Debian поставлен, 6.04? Совершенно подробный по информативности http://www.debian.org/index.ru.htmlЧитаем и разбираемся.